На языке Python в списке нужно удалить все элементы типа None и символов пустой строки ' '
С помощью цикла for я прохожусь по каждому элементу, проверяю его существование. Если его нет (пустая строка), то удаляю его из списка.
mass = ['', '', 'three', '']
for s in mass:
    if s:
        continue
    else:
        mass.remove(s)

Но если у меня подряд идет несколько пустых символов, то цикл удаляет только первый из них, а остальные перескакивает (смотрел через дебагер)
Почему Python пропускает в таком случае пустую строку, и как с этим бороться?
Заранее спасибо!

for s in mass[::-1]:

Nick, А почему это работает?...

Dark_knight228, установите for i, s in enumerate(mass): а после него print(i, s) , теперь посмотрите на вывод и подумайте, что происходит.

Получается, что интерпретатор видит все 4 элемента, включая пустые строки, это классно, но почему в моей проходке тогда он игнорировал второй пустой символ, стоящий после первого
А при работе со срезом всё получилось?..

Dark_knight228, ни при работе со срезом , а при считывании элементов списка в обратном порядке , т.е. от последнего к первому.  А в вашем случае,  при удалении элемента  вы укорачиваете список и сбиваются его индексы.

Точно!! Вы гений! Спасибо большое

mass = ['', '', 'three', '']
print([x for x in mass if x])


['three']

